# Simplest way to turn a number of indexed items into a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a bunch of things that have a `int size()` method and a `get(int i)` method, how can it most easily be streamed?

```
import nu.xom.Builder;
import nu.xom.Element;
import nu.xom.Elements;

// My builder.
Builder builder = new Builder();

class Thing {
    public Thing(Element from) {
        // Construct from an Element.
    }
}

private Stream<Thing> allThings(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException, ParsingException, IOException {
    Elements things = builder.build(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))
            .getRootElement().getChildElements();
    // Return a stream of `Thing`s created from all of the children.
    // How??
}
```

My attempt used an old-school `Iterable` and streamed that which seems unnecessarily messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
return IntStream.range(0, things.size())
          .mapToObj(things::get)
          .map(Thing::new);
```

Comment: I seem to forget the `IntStream` as a selector.That is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `Elements` class, it seems it only have (as you said) `get(int index)` and `size()` so I think your simplest option is to use an `IntStream` followed by `mapToObj`:

```
private Stream<Thing> allThings(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException, ParsingException, IOException {
    Elements things = builder.build(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))
            .getRootElement().getChildElements();
    return IntStream.range(0, things.size()).mapToObj(i -> new Thing(things.get(i)));
}
```